# Superfish not displaying sub menus

Tags: jquery, superfish

I have an issue with the latest version of superfish (v1.7.4). I have just installed it onto a [website here](http://justmaintenance.demomycms.co.uk/index.php). I'm using jQuery v1.10.1 to go with it, which is the same version in the examples. It works perfectly fine in the examples you download with superfish, however for some reason on my website it doesn't work.

When you hover over a drop down it adds the `sfHover` to the main `ul.sf-menu` instead of the `li` element I hover over, and doesn't remove the `display:none` from the ul sub menu that should be displaying.

As per a suggestion below I have stripped the page right back to just superfish and this issue is still persisting. I have never come across an issue like this before.

Can anyone suggest why this would be? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird how Superfish is behaving on your website. Since it works fine on its own, I'd suggest you strip down your webpage to just the Superfish, make sure it works, then start adding all the other stuff to the page one by one while testing Superfish. It could be that something else on the page is the cause. Let me know if you have any success.

Comment: I've stripped the page right back and it's still having the same issue.

Comment: It's your hoverintent.js. That's the one causing the weird behaviour of the Suckerfish. Get the latest copy or use the one from Suckerfish's download. Your hoverintent doesn't say which version it is, probably has some bug.

Comment: Aha, I didn't realise hoverIntent had been updated too. I thought that hadn't been updated in about 5 years. Thank you.